# How do I define main(String[] args) in Java without getting warnings and errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, program-entry-point

When I create a new main.java file in the default package in my Eclipse project, it generates a `main` method that looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
}
```

This immediately raises a warning that says `This method has a constructor name`.  The suggested fix is to remove the `void`:

```
public static main(String[] args)
{
}
```

Now rather than a warning, I get an error: `Illegal modifier for the constructor in type main; only public, protected & private are permitted`.  If I remove the `static`, my code now looks like:

```
public main(String[] args)
{
}
```

This time, I still get an error, but a different one that says:

```
Error: Main method not found in class main, please define the main method as:
    public static void main(String[] args)
```

Argggh!  But that takes me right back to where I started.  How do I define the main method so that I don't get any errors or warnings?

I'm using *Eclipse Juno Service Release 2* and *JavaSE-1.7*.  Please note, I'm very new to Java; I come from a C# background.  Also, this is probably a duplicate question, but I can't find it.

Comment: is your class called `main` as well?

Comment: You shouldn't use keywords like `main` as the names of your classes.

Comment: main is not a keyword. its only a convention

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't call your class `main`, but `Main`.

In general, stick to the Java coding standards: start class names with a capital (`Main` instead of `main`) and you won't run into these problems.

Answer (score 5):

If you name the file `main.java` the class has to be named `main` too, which is against standard (classes start with a capital letter) but possible. In a class a method named the same as the class is considered a constructor. So to fix your problem and fit the standard rename your class and the file to `Main` with a capital "M"

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of your class from `main` to `Main` or to something else. Also, following the [JavaBean API specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf), your classes must be in CamelCase with the first letter in capital.

Not 100% related with question, but you should also do not create classes with the names of Java JDK classes, for example `String`:

```
public class String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Try to execute this program!");
    }
}
```

This won't only give problems to compiler/JVM but also for future readers (remember that you are a future reader of your own code as well).

Note: to fix the code above, just refer to `java.lang.String` class using its full name:

```
public class String {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Try to execute this program!");
    }
}
```

Or even better, change the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the class name and file name must match.  If you have a file named main.java, then the class name has to be Main too, and in that case, the constructor method would be named main, so you couldn't have a main method.

Change your file and class name to something other than main.